# runOnUiThread from class that doesn't support it

Tags: android

I am editing this code from cSipSimple: https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/source/browse/trunk/CSipSimple/src/com/csipsimple/ui/incall/InCallCard.java?spec=svn2170&r=2170

And wish to add this method:

```
public void pushtotalk2(final View view) {

        final boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
        ((ToggleButton) view).setEnabled(false);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override


    public void run() {
            try {
                Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
                if (on) {

                    inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NUMPAD_MULTIPLY);
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_9);
                    Thread.sleep(500);

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            ((ToggleButton) view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_blue_glossy);
                            ((ToggleButton) view).setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POUND);
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_9);
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            ((ToggleButton) view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_lightblue_glossy);
                            ((ToggleButton) view).setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Failed to send keycodes: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

However I get the error: `runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){}) is undefined for the type new Thread(){}`

My understanding is that the activity class has this method, but how do I access it from my code?

I tried making a  constructor and got this error:

`Implicit super constructor FrameLayout() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor`

Any ideas on how this is done correctly?

Comment: post your class code full. `runOnUiThread` is a method of activity class. So you need Activity context.

Comment: @Raghunandan I posted the full code in the link.

Comment: @Tarsem that is what I am trying to do and do not know how.

Comment: @Paul: Did you try what I wrote? You don't even need the Activity.

Comment: @Carnal I did and it worked thank you, now I am just wondering out of learning/curiosity.

Comment: @Paul try Carnal's Answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you want to run something in the UI Thread from a non `Activity` class, you can use a `Handler` instead.

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
         ((ToggleButton) view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_blue_glossy);
         ((ToggleButton) view).setEnabled(true);
     }
});
```

Comment: thank you that does indeed remove the error, Is there a way to actually pass this runonui method from activity to this view in any way?

Comment: @Paul: I don't see why you wouldn't choose this solution. But yes, you can add Activity as a param in "pushtotalk2" method, and call activity.runOnUi....

Comment: Just take a Context as param and call pushtotalk2(view, this) from activity. You dont need to pass the whole Activity object, which is also bad practice imo as it can cause memory leaks unless using WeakReference or so. That would indeed be overkill for a Toast message. Or even better.. look into the callback pattern http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html, this way you can keep the Activity relevant stuff in you Activity

Answer (score 1):

runOnUiThread is not defined for Views. Only for Activities. And InCallCard is just a view.

You can use the post(Runnable) method instead of runOnUiThread().